# How to count entries based on criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have this column where I put the date when I performed some action, along with a hyperlink in it (`=hyperlink("link", "action date"`). I want to count how many of these actions were performed in the current month.

I can convert it to the month number just fine by using `=MONTH(cell)`, but when I try to use `COUNTIF()`, it always gives `0`

Formula I'm using:

```
=COUNTIF(MONTH(B5:B), "=month(now())")
```

I noticed the countif formula works if I only reference a single cell on the first argument, so if there is a way to iterate over all cells checking against the month and then adding those 1's, that would work too, but I can't conceive that formula in my head.

Thanks for the help!

Sample data:

```
Client 1    11 Jul 18   

Client 2    12 Dec 18   

Client 3    15 Aug 18   

Client 4    15 Jan 19   

Client 5    17 Jan 19   

Client 6    18 Jan 19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(MONTH(B5:B), "="&MONTH(TODAY())))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :]
What does the & in the &MONTH do anyway?

Comment: @BrunoMaio MONTH() is a regular formula that's why it needs to be outside from double quotes. & is for appending it to "=" which needs to be inside of double quotes. MONTH(TODAY()) will return you the number of today's month